# GRUB doesn't show up installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 10, on a UEFI x64 HP laptop

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 alongside Windows 10, on a x64 UEFI HP laptop.

I burned the Ubuntu (64bit version) on the usb using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/), proceeded without problems with the installation of Ubuntu, and then rebooted the laptop. However, this resulted in the laptop just booting into windows with no grub appearing.

I consequently tried a variety of things. For example I followed the steps outlined in [this](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) guide:

1. Disabled UEFI secure boot and Windows 10 fast boot option
2. Reinstalled again Ubuntu 14.04 from the USB
3. Ran boot-repair from the ubuntu live installation. Boot-repair completed without giving errors. It said to have successfully repaired the GRUB, and in case the GRUB still didn't show up to run the following command on a Windows 10 administrator terminal: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`.
4. From Windows 10 I run the above command, which executed without errors. Rebooting the system however the GRUB still doesn't show up. I also tried the slightly different version of the same command given in the [above linked](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) page, but still no luck.

I'm not sure what else I can try to make it work, I've never had such problems in installing a linux distribution alongside Windows on other laptops.
Any help is appreciated at this point.

#### Update

I ***did*** found a way to boot into Ubuntu through the GRUB. Holding down `F11` during the booting process, Windows will boot into the blue "safe mode". In there if you select the "chose a booting device" option you will have the choice to boot from a series of devices, including *GRUB* and *Ubuntu* (which however both result in booting from the GRUB). Here is a photo of this menu (sorry for the non-english language, the title says "Use a device"):

[image]

While this method works, it is obviously a pain to have to do this procedure every time, but this proves that grub is installed correctly. "Only" the boot loader priority seems to be messed up. ***How can I force the boot loader to boot into GRUB instead of windows?***

#### Additional information:

1. The laptop is an HP Notebook - 15-ac119nl (ENERGY STAR)
2. Here is a snapshot of the partition table given by gparted:
   [image]
3. Here is the output of `bcdedit` on Windows 10:

[image]

Comment: A bit off topic, but what other distributions have you successfully installed alongside Windows 10? I'm a bit unclear on your blanket statement regarding installing alongside Windows when it seems this question regards a specific version of Windows (10 to be precise).

Comment: Both ubuntu and other linux distributions, but never on this particular laptop, and really never alongside Windows 10 neither. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, though. This question is specifically about installing ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on this particular laptop.

Comment: Sorry, It wasn't my intent to be unclear My question was prompted by your statement that " I've never had such problems in installing a linux distribution alongside Windows on other laptops. "

Comment: Related: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2955460/operating-systems/dual-booting-linux-with-windows-what-you-need-to-know.html I'm sorry I don't have more for you but I'm personally busy avoiding Windows 10 as I'm not interested in "beta testing" for Microsoft and I don't own that particular laptop.

Comment: HP only likes to boot Windows: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 2):

*I know this is old but for anyone who comes across this, heres how I solved it. It based on the info in the link oldfred posted.*

### Problem

I had the same problem on a **HP Laptop**. There are a lot of laptops which love to boot windows as priority despite what you configure. You need to **overwrite** the windows boot manager with the grub. It's a bit of a hack, but it's worked great for me and others. *Windows will overwrite this every time it updates.*

### Solution

I created an SH (script file) with the following commands and run it as sudo. (make sure your boot partition is mounted at `/boot/efi`, which it should be by default)

```
7z a /boot/efi/EFI_`date +\%d\%m\%Y`.7z /boot/efi/EFI/
cp -a /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/* /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

### Notes

The script basically backs up the current EFI configuration (using 7zip, modify this to your preferred flavor of backup), then overwrites the efi boot scripts of the windows boot manager.

It will need to be run everytime windows does a major update.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't have the laptop that gave me this problem at hand anymore, so I can't really apply or try this, but it will likely by useful to someone else googling for the same (very frustrating) problem

Answer (score 1):

Tried this command in your windows cmd (as administrator)

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

If that not works, try this

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\bootx64.efi
```

Comment: I've already tried the one with `grubx64`, as I said in the question. I will try the one with `bootx64`. Do you have any source for this information?

Comment: @glance just notice that, use [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) on your windows, it is now supported Windows 10. See [this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/) for documentation.